# Embed rate number up down widget in panel node

Tags: rating

I am using rate module and the number up down widget, and in the settings for this module I had set it to appear at the top of content. It was appearing fine. However, now I am using a panel for this node and the widget no longer appears as expected. I need to embed it into my panel. How would I go about this? I have done a few searchs and found rate_embed, but I am not having any luck getting this to work. I have tried the following. My rate widget is called 'points', and its settings are at /admin/structure/rate/:

function:

```
<?php rate_embed(&$node, $machine_name, $mode = RATE_FULL); ?>
```

What I tried:

```
<?php print rate_embed($node, 'points', $mode = RATE_FULL); ?>
<?php echo rate_embed($node, 'points', $mode = RATE_FULL); ?>
```

this was giving an error that rate_embed was acting on a non-object.

Comment: you have to display only count value alone?

Comment: No, I want to display the actual widget itself in my panel so that a plus / minus number button appears for the user to vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
 $up_down = rate_generate_widget('1', 'node', {current node id}, RATE_FULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
 print render($up_down);
```

Comment: this module could also work nicely with this code: http://drupal.org/project/widgets

Comment: how would I get the current node id in there? curently that code gives:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/andrewwe/public_html/wequest.co.uk/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 4

Comment: You can get node id as arg(1). Verify did you enabled rating for that particular content type /admin/structure/rate/